# Pytorch working with different tensors length

Tags: python, pytorch

I am working with word embeddings, and each phrase has different length.
My dataset contains a list of vectors, one vector of size 300 for each word in the phrase.
Maybe one phrase has 20 words, maybe it has 2, etc.

For instance:

```
X.iloc[0:10, ]
0    [[-0.51389, -0.55286, -0.28648, -0.18608, -0.0...
1    [[0.33837, -0.13933, -0.096114, 0.40103, 0.041...
2    [[-0.078564, 0.18702, -0.35168, 0.067557, 0.11...
3    [[0.047356, -0.10216, -0.15738, -0.04521, 0.26...
4    [[0.16781, -0.31793, -0.21877, 0.28025, 0.3364...
5    [[-0.4509, 0.077681, -0.058347, 0.2859, -0.369...
6    [[0.018223, -0.012323, 0.035569, 0.24232, -0.1...
7    [[-0.19265, 0.45863, -0.33841, -0.16293, -0.26...
8    [[0.10751, 0.15958, 0.13332, 0.16642, -0.03273...
9    [[0.35259, 0.60833, 0.051335, -0.079285, -0.35...
Name: embedding, dtype: object

len(X.iloc[0])
313
len(X.iloc[1])
2
```

The targets are just a numeric integer, from 0 to 5.

How can I pad this sequence using pytorch to feed a neural network of fixed size?
I saw something with `collate_fn`, however I think it only works for batches, and not for the whole dataset.

Comment: You should pad/truncate the sequence to have the same length at least for within the same batch.

Comment: @TYZ should't be all the inputs, not for the batch, but for the whole dataset padded to the same length? Why only the batch? Also I'm asking how to pad them

Comment: Assuming you are using recurrent, transformers-like models, as long as the sequence length within the batch is the same, then it should be fine. For "how to pad", you should do your google first before asking. There are lots of ways for padding and truncation, you need to judge what works for your case the best.

Comment: `as long as the sequence length within the batch is the same, then it should be fine` 
How is that? I already looked it up, and came with the `collate_fn`, but as I said, I thought it was only for batches, so as you are saying me that it doesn't matter I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct that *collate_fn* can help in this case. Indeed, it is applied on batch level, but iterating through all batches will process entire dataset.
For padding you can use some of the following functions:

[torch.nn.functional.pad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pad.html)

[torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html)

Doing it manually in a custom way is also an option.

Here is toy example with torch.nn.functional.pad and random dataset:

```
import torch
import random
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset


MAX_PHRASE_LENGTH = 20


class PhraseDataset(Dataset):

    def __len__(self):
        return 5

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        phrase = torch.rand((random.randint(2, MAX_PHRASE_LENGTH), 300), dtype=torch.float)
        target = torch.tensor(random.randint(0, 5), dtype=torch.float)

        return phrase, target


def collate_fn(batch):
    targets = []
    phrases = []
    for (phrase, target) in batch:
        targets.append(target)
        padding = MAX_PHRASE_LENGTH - phrase.size()[0]
        if padding > 0:
            phrases.append(F.pad(phrase, (0, 0, padding, 0), "constant", 0))
        else:
            phrases.append(phrase)

    return torch.stack(phrases), torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.float)


dataset = PhraseDataset()
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=5, collate_fn=collate_fn)

for phrases, targets in data_loader:
    print('Phrases size:', phrases.size())
```

Output:

```
Phrases size: torch.Size([5, 20, 300])
```

Although padding could actually be applied in a dataset, before *collate_fn* is called, so *collate_fn* won't be needed in this case at all.